# Date Difference in Days doesn't calculate correctly

Tags: php

I am not sure if I am going crazy or have missed something simple.
I am simply trying to get the difference between 2 dates in days but it doesn't show what I think it should.

I am currently using the following code

```
$firstDate  = new DateTime("06/09/2021");
$secondDate = new DateTime("05/01/2022");
$intvl = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);

// Total amount of days
echo $intvl->days . " days ";
```

This returns: 326 days but it should be 121...

Am I doing something wrong here, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `m/d/y` vs `d-m-Y`: https://3v4l.org/ggock

Comment: `06/09` can be Jun 9 or Sep 6, it depends on who you ask. Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: 326 days is correct if 05 and 05 are the month and 09 and 01 are days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input dates are ambiguous: is "06/09/2021" the 6th September (as a UK reader would assume) or 9th June (as a US reader would assume)? The US interpretation leads to the 326 days PHP is returning; the UK interpretation leads to the 121 days you were expecting.

It's better to either specify the format you're expecting, with [`DateTime::createFromFormat(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), or to use an unambiguous format, such as "2021-09-06".

You might also want to get into the habit of using the [DateTimeImmutable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) class, which is generally less confusing to work with.

So:

```
$firstDate  = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", "06/09/2021");
$secondDate = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", "05/01/2022");
$intvl = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);
echo $intvl->days . " days ";
// 121 days

$firstDate  = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", "06/09/2021");
$secondDate = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", "05/01/2022");
$intvl = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);
echo $intvl->days . " days ";
// 326 days

$firstDate  = new DateTimeImmutable("2021-09-06");
$secondDate  = new DateTimeImmutable("2022-01-05");
$intvl = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);
echo $intvl->days . " days ";
// 121 days
```

Comment: @DannyBroadhurst Don't you mean "121 of those days"? 

Answer (score 0):

9th June 2021 to 1st May 2022 is definitely 326 days.

By any chance are you expecting that PHP will interpret these as 6th September and 5th January? If we [read the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) for the DateTime constructor, the linked article shows us the formats which it can parse by default. Based on what you've provided, it will assume it's `m/d/Y` rather than `d/m/Y`.

If you need to parse other formats which aren't supported by the default parser, then you need to use the [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function to generate the DateTime object, rather than the constructor.

e.g.

```
$firstDate  = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", "06/09/2021");
$secondDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", "05/01/2022");
$intvl = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);

// Total amount of days
echo $intvl->days . " days ";
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f1689615f5813dbf699d92c70ad1679a9a96e4f

---

Alternatively, to avoid any ambiguity, it's generally a good idea wherever possible to generate and pass your date strings around in an ISO8601-compatible format which has no other recognised (mis-)interpretations, e.g. `Y-m-d`:

```
$firstDate  = new DateTime("2021-09-06");
$secondDate = new DateTime("2022-01-05");
$intvl = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);

// Total amount of days
echo $intvl->days . " days ";
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/506cbe95dee91736bcc1e33ae57d02cdaf258114